# Thread Waits for a lock when it shouldn't be

Tags: java, multithreading

i am practicing on java threads, and i am confused with Locking mechanism, 
What i am trying to achieve is when a thread is taking much time to execute a block of code whose lock it has acquired, the other thread should just not wait and go for the else condition,

this is my code as follows

```
    import java.util.concurrent.locks.*;
    import java.util.concurrent.*;

    class MySharedData{
    private volatile boolean bFlag;
    private int counter=1;
    public void abuseIt() throws Exception{
    while(!bFlag){
            System.out.println(" THREAD "+Thread.currentThread().getName()+" WITH COUNTER "+counter);
            counter++;  
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
            if(counter > 20){
                bFlag=true;
            }
        }
    }
    }


    class RequesterThree implements Runnable{
     private Lock lock;
    RequesterThree(){
     lock = new ReentrantLock();
    }   
    @Override
     public void run(){
     MySharedData myShared = null;
     try{
           myShared = new MySharedData();
           if(lock.tryLock(250,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){             
                myShared.abuseIt();
            }else{
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": SHARED DATA IS NON-ACCESSIBLE !!!!");
            }           
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }finally{
            lock.unlock();
        }       
    }
    }

    public class Ex03{
       public static void main(String [] args){
        Thread[] requests = new Thread[]{
            new Thread(new RequesterThree(),"MICHEAL"),
            new Thread(new RequesterThree(),"SHAWN"),
            new Thread(new RequesterThree(),"JOHN"),
            new Thread(new RequesterThree(),"TRON"),
            new Thread(new RequesterThree(),"FINCH")
        };
        for(int x=0; x < requests.length; x++){
            requests[x].start();
        }   
    }
    }
```

But here all of the five threads wait for the lock, and not a single thread prints the SOP in the else condition,

What i am expecting is,

When Thread T1 is started, it acquires the lock, and execute the abuseIt() method, there it sleeps for 1 sec,

Now thread T2 should wait for the lock to get free for only 250 milisec, but T1 is any how waiting for 1 sec, so T2 should execute the else condition in the run method,

How can i achieve this,

Comment: Fix your code so it doesn't unlock the lock unless it locks it. Also, I don't see where you initialize `bFlag`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, each `RequesterThree` object has a separate lock, so there is no synchronization across them.

Additionally, each thread calls `myShared.abuseIt()` on its own dedicated instance of `MySharedData`.

To fix:

```
 private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
 private static final MySharedData myShared = new MySharedData();
```

Also, remove the constructor and the change the `run()` method:

```
 @Override
 public void run(){
 try{
       if(lock.tryLock(250,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)){
```

Finally, your code can call `unlock()` even if `tryLock()` hasn't succeeded. This needs to be fixed.

Comment: What about passing same RequesterThree object to all the Threads in the array in main method ?

Answer (score 1):

Make your lock field final static

```
...
class RequesterThree implements Runnable{
     private static final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    RequesterThree(){

    }  
...
```